# ATmega64 custom board is not programming

Tags: avr, schematics, error, programmer

I have designed a custom board for [ATmega64](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATmega64) as below:

[image: Schematic of the ATmega64 part]

It's the first time I want to program it, and I get a "chip enable program error". I can program [ATmega16](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/atmega16) and [ATmega8](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATmega8), but for ATmega64 I get this error.

I also connect the jumper of the slow clock in the programmer and pen pin to the ground or unconnected and both don't program.

I picked up the 10 µH inductor and it's short circuit now.
Is there a problem with my schematics or what should I do?

Answer (score 7):

The programming connector is not connected to In-System Programming pins.

You need to connect to the programming data pins PDI and PDO, not the SPI MOSI and MISO.

Please see datasheet pin mapping for serial programming.

On the bright side, if you make a new board, you can now fix other bugs too, such as AVCC inductor having a capacitor on the chip side, and the RTC crystal caps seem way too high as well.

Comment: Page 306 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/atmel-2490-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega64-l_datasheet.pdf) to be exact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you said and now it works well.

Comment: @MojtabaMiraki If you find the answer correct and it solves the problem then mark it as correct answer.